# Why ASYNC await acts differently in this code?

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
//1 code
async function test(){
    const a1 = await new Promise((res,rej)=>{
        setTimeout(()=>{
      return res("5 second promise")
        },5000)
   })
 
   console.log("first")
   const a2 = await new Promise((res,rej)=>{
    setTimeout(()=>{
    return res("2 second promise")
    },2000)
})
   
   console.log("second")
}
test();

//2 code
const p1 = new Promise((res,rej)=>{
    setTimeout(()=>{
  return res("5 second promise")
    },5000)
})

const p2 =  new Promise((res,rej)=>
    setTimeout(()=>{
    return res("2 second promise")
 }),2000)

async function test2(){
   await p1;
   console.log("first")
   await p2;
   console.log("second")

}
test2();
```

Code 1 prints "first" in 5 secs and then "second" after 2 seconds
Code 2 prints "first" and "second" after 5 seconds

I have  questions

1. why same code  acting differently?
2. If we call await it suspends that function then how come the second await p2 which has delay of 2 seconds is getting completed in same time that of first await p1 which has delay of 5 seconds, await p1 should complete in 5 seconds and after 2 seconds await p2 should suspend function and paused and print "second" after 2 seconds.
3. what's the difference which made code 1 to run properly ??

I am not getting be async is meant to pause at await and function is suspended how come the second await p2's time is also started with p1 if the code in that line is not hit yet as its paused by first await.

Comment: In snippet 1 the "2-second" promise is created only after the "5-second" promise resolved. In snippet 2 both promises are created at the (more or less) same time, thus, when the "5-second" promise resolves, also the "2-second" promise is long resolved ...

Comment: So if i am on line await p1 so it should wait there by suspending function and if so how come the timeout set for p2 also started resolving?

Comment: Because the second promise (and therefore its 2-second timeout) is long created before you even started `await`ing the first promise ...

Answer (score 0):

> 1. why same code acting differently?

Because it's not the same code. Your first example is only scheduling the second timer once the first has fired, but your second example is scheduling both timers, one right after the other, and only waiting later.

The fundamental thing here is that the code in the function you pass `new Promise` is run **immediately** (and synchronously) when you call `new Promise`, not *later* when you use `await` (or directly call `then`). This is a common misunderstanding about the `Promise` constructor and promises generally. By the time you have a promise, the work it will report on is *already* underway.¹ Waiting for the promise doesn't start the work.

So in your first code block, you call `new Promise`, which calls `setTimeout`, and then the function waits until that promise is settled five seconds later; only at that point does it call `new Promise` and `setTimeout` again, starting the two-second timeout.

But in your second code block, you call `new Promise` and `setTimeout` twice, one right after the other, without doing any waiting. So both timers are running.

This is clearer if you log what's happening (I normally suggest using the debugger, but for asynchronous timing stuff, sometimes logging is better):

```html
<script type="module">
//1 code
async function test() {
    const a1 = await new Promise((res, rej) => {
        console.log("a1's timer set for 5000ms");
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log("a1's timer fired");
            return res("5 second promise");
        }, 5000);
    });

    console.log("first");
    const a2 = await new Promise((res, rej) => {
        console.log("a2's timer set for 2000ms");
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log("a2's timer fired");
            return res("2 second promise");
        }, 2000);
    });

    console.log("second");
}
test();
</script>
```

vs.

```html
<script type="module">
//2 code
const p1 = new Promise((res, rej) => {
    console.log("p1's timer set for 5000ms");
    setTimeout(() => {
        console.log("p1's timer fired");
        return res("5 second promise");
    }, 5000);
});

const p2 = new Promise((res, rej) => {
    console.log("p2's timer set for 2000ms");
    setTimeout(() => {
        console.log("p2's timer fired");
        return res("2 second promise");
    }, 2000);
});

async function test2() {
    await p1;
    console.log("first");
    await p2;
    console.log("second");
}
test2();
</script>
```

> 2. If we call await it suspends that function then how come the second await p2 which has delay of 2 seconds is getting completed in same time that of first await p1 which has delay of 5 seconds

Because by the time the first promise has settled, the second promise has also settled, since the timers were started at the same time and the second timer's delay was shorter.

> ...await p1 should complete in 5 seconds and after 2 seconds await p2 should suspend function and paused and print "second" after 2 seconds.

It would, if you started the timer *after* the 5-second delay, as you do in your first example. But that's not what the second example does.

> 3. what's the difference which made code 1 to run properly ??

The difference is when you call `setTimeout` to schedule the second timer. In the first example, you don't call it until the first promise has settled. In the second, you call it immediately after the call for the first timer, so both timers are running at the same time.

---

¹ There have been a couple of Promise implementations that didn't start the work until the first time you called `then` (directly, or indirectly via `await`), but they're rare and that's not how JavaScript's standard promises behave. (Doing it that way is allowed by [the language-neutral promises spec](https://promisesaplus.com) because it's intentionally very thin, and doesn't talk about promise creation; but the vast majority of implementations, including JavaScript's, expect the work to be underway by the time you have the promise. If you want something that will start the work later when you call it, that's what functions are for.)